# How to constrain a variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab newb here. I have searched and haven't found how to do the following:

```
x=0.1:1/100:10;
y=exp(a(a>=-1&a<=1)*sqrt(x));
plot(x,y)
```

I realize that the dimensions of `x` and `a` don't match, but I just want to express: "what does `y` look like when a constant, `a`, is constrained between -1 and 1", for example.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answers below don't help, perhaps you might revise your question. It seems to me that you want to explore the shape of exp(a*sqrt(x) as a varies, but I might be wrong. If so, do you want a 3-d plot of y vs x and a, or a set of traces of y vs x for different a? If so, over what range should a vary?

Comment: I was just hoping for 2D and "set of traces of y vs x for different a. I actually have different ranges of a I am interested in, but in the example I provided, I am interested in -1 <= a <= 1. I am realizing there are often multiple ways to approach problem solving in Matlab so if you have more input, please, I'd like to here it. Later when I get points I can revisit here to give you some. The answers below were very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a` and `x` are independent, you can go along these lines, using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to compute `y` for all combinations of `a` and `x`:

```
x = 0.1:1/100:10; %// define x values
a = linspace(-1,1,10); %// define a values
y = exp( bsxfun(@times, a, sqrt(x).') ); %'// compute y for all combinations
plot(x,y); %// this plots each column of y. Each colum represents a value of a
```

[image]

Or plot as a 3D graph (`y` as a function of `a` and `x`):

```
mesh(a,x,y)
xlabel('a')
ylabel('x')
zlabel('y')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Luis, looking in the docs, thanks to your suggestion, I see that bsxfun is a really useful function.

Comment: @Joe I discovered `bsxfun` here in StackOverflow, some months ago, and it definitely changed the way I think (in Matlab) :-)

Comment: Luis Mendo, do you happen to know of a way to have labels showing a's value affixed to each different trace of y given a, i.e., for each column of y?

Comment: @Joe If you want that you have to place the labels manually: `gtext('a=-1')`, place it with the mouse, etc. I suggest you use `legend` instead: for example, use `legend(num2str(a.',3))`

Comment: Thanks Luis Mendo. Great tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
x=0.1:1/100:10;    % 991 clips
a=-1:1/495:1;      % use 1/495 here to make it also 991 clips
y=exp(a.*sqrt(x));
plot(x,y)
```

This will give you the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you herohyongtao, another helpful suggestion. Appreciated.

Comment: We can do a=-1:1/floor(length(x)/2):1;      % use 1/495 here to make it also 991 clips

Comment: I kind of generalized this pattern for myself and anyone else it might help: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8904953

Comment: Given my specs, this really should have been the answer, sorry herohuyangtoa. This is because your answer allows me to vary the range of a in non-uniform ways which was my desire as per the gist above.